# Why can JWT iat get smaller than nbf in very rare cases?

Tags: jwt, identityserver4, appauth

In rare cases in iOS and Android, the JWT attribute iat contains a smaller value than in nbf.

For this reason, the user gets the error message "ID Token expired". This also makes sense, but the question is why the time in iat can become smaller than nbf?

Is there a way to prevent iat from becoming smaller than nbf in identityserver4?

This can never be reproduced with via webbrowser (NextAuth.js). For the authentication in iOS and Android we use appauth-iOS and appauth-android.

In case of the mentioned error we get tokens like this:

```
{
  "nbf": 1621951659,
  "exp": 1621951959,
  "iss": "issuer",
  "aud": "apps",
  "nonce": "V82ztq0cxNqslpVNsm_YYJZKJVUVhSpZlniB9hrXZ_o",
  "iat": 1621951658,
  "at_hash": "poDvhvDZ8EF__10uJiB2tQ",
  "s_hash": "1gg8istJoI9ATRN3H814rw",
  "sid": "F3559C9E64428AC1EA384588519CFBFB",
  "sub": "test@email.com",
  "auth_time": 1621951656,
  "idp": "local",
  "family_name": "Muster",
  "given_name": "Peter",
  "ClientId": "testapp",
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How much time difference is between those values? Most client libraries need to take into account some kind of clock drift.

Comment: the time difference between iat and nbf is only one second. does the iat value come from the identityserver or from the client library?

Comment: I guess both timestamps are created separately but usually it all happens within a second. But when the first  timestamp (iat) is taken at let's say 12:00:00.999, then nbf might be created at 12:00:01.000, just 1 millisecond later but resulting in one second difference.